# React-native passing component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to pass one React component to my CustomTab component.
So i have something like this :

```
const FirstRoute = () => <View style={[ styles.container, { backgroundColor: '#ff4081' } ]} />;
const SecondRoute = () => <View style={[ styles.container, { backgroundColor: '#673ab7' } ]} />; 

export default class Profile extends Component {
_renderScene = SceneMap({
    first: FirstRoute,
    second: SecondRoute,
});
render() {
return (
    <CustomTab scenes={this._renderScene}/>
);
}
```

In my CustomTab i have :

```
export default class CustomTab extends React.Component {
_renderScene = this.props.scenes;

render() {

return (
    <TabViewAnimated
        style={styles.container}
        navigationState={this.state}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
```

but this is not working, looks like passed parameter is wrong .It is possible to achieve that ?
Thx for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, you need to assign `_renderScene` variable in render or `constructor` however there is not need for you to assign `this.props.scenes` to another class variable you could just directly use it

```
export default class CustomTab extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TabViewAnimated
                style={styles.container}
                navigationState={this.state}
                renderScene={this.props. scenes}
```

Comment: Hi thx for feedback. Unfortunately this is also not working. I don't get any error, i just get white view and as you see in my post first and second route has backgroundColor set.

Comment: Is `navigationState={this.state}` present in CustomTab component

Comment: No, where should i place it ?
This exactly this example, i just create CustomTab :
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view

Comment: when you are passing navigationState to custom component it should present in CustomTab like `state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [{ key: 'first', title: 'First' }, { key: 'second', title: 'Second' }],
  };`

Comment: Yes, the state is there in CustomTab
state = {
        index: 0,
        routes: [
            { key: 'first', title: 'First' },
            { key: 'second', title: 'Second' },
        ],
    };

Comment: Sorry for misleading answer previously. If you want i can post whole both files, but the main component looks like in this example what i post. I just only created new component, moved there views and pass them as argument to main component.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `_renderScene` property in constructor or other react component life cycle methods like.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._renderScene = this.props.scenes;
}
```

Comment: Hi thx for feedback. Unfortunately this is also not working. I don't get any error, i just get white view and as you see in my post first and second route has backgroundColor set.

Comment: Did you call it directly  renderScene={this.props.scenes}

Comment: Yes. If this logic is in CustomTab, then everything is working fine. The problem is in passing this parameter...